# Using button from the function submit_button() triggers alert

Tags: buttons

I have placed a submit button in the admin section of the add/edit screen of a custom post type with the submit_button() function.

When I click this, it shows an alert screen (see screenshot below).

How can I prevent this alert from showing?

Thanks in advance!
-Kevin

[image: alert from submit button]

Comment: Do you happen to know what it says in English?

Comment: It says something like:

'Leave website? Any changes you've made, might not be saved.'

Comment: The standard 'Save draft' button (which I'm trying to replicate) doesn't trigger an alert. I would like to achieve the same with the custom button.

I followed this reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/submit_button/